# Get Id / Xpath from a list of elements to access it depends on variable

Tags: python, selenium, browser-automation

[Categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxHWw.png)emphasized text

Hey Folks,

I have a Variable (String) in Python which is one of 14 categories (electronic, clothes ... ). I now want to click on the specific element in web which is equal to my variable.
All the categories in the web have the same class_name.

```
for elm in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('category-selection-list-item-link'):
print(elm.xpath)
```

Here I have a list with all the strings of the categories. I need now the specific xpath or id for each to then being able to access it.

I hope you understand my issue and are able to help!
Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is pass the category to the below xpath.

```
//*[@class='category-selection-list-item-link'][normalize-space(.)='category_name_goes_here']
```

Now use this xpath in your script as shown below.

```
# below script will click on Jobs category item.
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='category-selection-list-item-link'][normalize-space(.)='Jobs']").click
```